# Best way to archive about 100 values from one table to another in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table containing the balances of about 100 accounts (it's variable). One record per account. The balances are continually updated but I would like to find the best way to archive the current balance each day.

I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Table schemas:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `acc_bals`
--
-- Holds the tracks the balances of all coa's and bank accounts
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `acc_bals` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `acc_type` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL comment '1 - coa; 2 - bank accounts',
    `acc_id` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL,
    `acct_balance` VARBINARY(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  engine=InnoDB DEFAULT charset=utf8 auto_increment=1;

--
-- Table structure for table `balance_archive`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `balance_archive` (
  `id` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'Beginning of the day for which this value was archived for..',
  `coa_id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign ID of COA.',
  `bal` varbinary(27) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Archived COA balance at beginning of specified date.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The reason for the varbinary columns is because the balances are encrypted.

I was originally thinking to query `acc_bals` and put all the account id's and values into an array, having decrypted the values, and then run a second query and for each item in the array, copy it into the archive table.

It then occurred to me that I probably do not need to decrypt the values at all which would save a lot of processing and then further more, it might be possible to do this in a single query?

If my approach seems right, perhaps someone can suggest how that query might look please?

I'm using MySQL PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple select into will do in a recurring event set for each day.
Something like :

```
insert into balance_archive (date,coa_id,bal)
select now(),ab.id,ab.acct_balance
from acc_bals ab
```

That way you don't need to use PHP at all, you can do it with MySql only.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm getting "#1327 - Undeclared variable: balance_archive" though. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong when running the query? It seems to think that the recipient table name is a variable rather than a table name. I tried putting it in back-ticks but no avail.

Comment: @PeterSnow I've corrected the query, I think that's the syntax for MySQL